# String before class name in a Java exception

Tags: java, fedora

In this java exception I don't understand what mean the java/base and java/desktop string before the class name:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.ea.28-2.fc29.i386/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2620)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:767)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1831)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2430)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2487)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2684)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2638)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1867)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1399)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1397)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1396)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1429)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:621)
```

In this other exception, for example, they do not appear:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at it.dsestili.jhashcode.ui.MainWindow.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you know [Java Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)?

Comment: No, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.base` and `java.desktop` are `module` names. You can get the list of modules by using the following command:

```
java --list-modules
```

Note that `module` was introduced in Java 9. Therefore, the command given above will error out if you use it with an older version of Java.